# spring-data Slice with specification without Count

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm wondering if there is simple way (or at least plan to add the feature) how to return [Slice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) without count query while passing specification to [JpaSpecificationExecutor .findAll(Specification spec,
                Pageable pageable)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html#findAll-org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification-org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable-)

So I want to do something like this:

```
Slice<MessageViewEntity> messageViewEntities =
                messageViewRepository.findAll(
                        messageViewRepository.withSearchSpecifications(language, categoryId, messageKey, longText),
                        new PageRequest(page, size)
                );
```

Where count query won't be executed.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26738199/how-to-disable-count-when-specification-and-pageable-are-used-together) which is almost 2 years old but in current release 10.1.2 I don't see method/way how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. Look here: 
https://gist.github.com/tcollins/0ebd1dfa78028ecdef0b

Basically you need to:

- extend SimpleJpaRepository so you have access to protected getQuery(Specification ..) methof returning TypedQuery
- then on typed query you can set offset & max results (size of slice + 1)
- then you can execute TypedQuery .getResultList() & create Slice result