# Page<> vs Slice<> when to use which?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I've read in Spring Jpa Data [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) about two different types of objects when you 'page' your dynamic queries made out of repositories.

**Page** and **Slice**

```
Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);

Slice<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

So, I've tried to find some articles or anything talking about main difference and different **usages** of both, how **performance** changes and how **sorting** affercts both type of queries.

Does anyone has this type of knowledge, articles or some good source of information?

Comment: My bet is that `Page` triggers an additional `count` query to know the total number of pages/elements, while `Slice` does not.

Comment: I agree with @sp00m. Actually, Page is implementing Slice when you look at the source code. So from a performance perspective, you should use Page when you need the overall count and Slice otherwise.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters

Comment: You have accepted an answer that doesn't treat the "sorting" question - eg. how are Slice and Page behaving when a sorting operation is added. Did you find out if there is any difference between them when sorting is involved ? I am asking this because sorting will also imply a full read of records.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`Page`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) extends [`Slice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) and knows the total number of elements and pages available by triggering a count query. From the Spring Data JPA [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters):

> A `Page` knows about the total number of elements and pages available. It does so by the infrastructure triggering a count query to calculate the overall number. As this might be expensive depending on the store used, `Slice` can be used as return instead. A `Slice` only knows about whether there’s a next `Slice` available which might be just sufficient when walking through a larger result set.

Comment: Yeah, i've read that. I was wondering if the difference is bigger than that, but as I see it isn't. That answer seems sufficient : ) thanks to all

Comment: `Slice has information about whether the next or previous object exists or not.`  I find it problematic when I used the `Page`

Comment: @cassiomolin, Does returning a List<Entity> from the repo method is more performant than Slice<Entity>, and of course Page<Entity> ?

Comment: But is there any difference between Page and Slice if both make an order by ?

Answer (score 8):

The main difference between `Slice` and `Page` is the latter provides non-trivial pagination details such as total number of records(`getTotalElements()`), total number of pages(`getTotalPages()`), and next-page availability status(`hasNext()`) that satisfies the query conditions, on the other hand, the former only provides pagination details such as next-page availability status(`hasNext()`) compared to its counterpart `Page`. `Slice` gives significant performance benefits when you deal with a colossal table with burgeoning records.

Let's dig deeper into its technical implementation of both variants.

- [Page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/48597dca246178c0d7e6952425004849d3fb02c0/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L169)

```
static class PagedExecution extends JpaQueryExecution {
    @Override
    protected Object doExecute(final AbstractJpaQuery repositoryQuery, JpaParametersParameterAccessor accessor) {

        Query query = repositoryQuery.createQuery(accessor);
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(query.getResultList(), accessor.getPageable(),
                () -> count(repositoryQuery, accessor));
    }

    private long count(AbstractJpaQuery repositoryQuery, JpaParametersParameterAccessor accessor) {

        List<?> totals = repositoryQuery.createCountQuery(accessor).getResultList();
        return (totals.size() == 1 ? CONVERSION_SERVICE.convert(totals.get(0), Long.class) : totals.size());
    }
}
```

If you observe the above code snippet, PagedExecution#doExecute method underlyingly calls PagedExecution#count method to get the total number of records satisfying the condition.

- [Slice](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/48597dca246178c0d7e6952425004849d3fb02c0/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L136)

```
    static class SlicedExecution extends JpaQueryExecution {
    @Override
    protected Object doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery query, JpaParametersParameterAccessor accessor) {

        Pageable pageable = accessor.getPageable();
        Query createQuery = query.createQuery(accessor);

        int pageSize = 0;
        if (pageable.isPaged()) {

            pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
            createQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize + 1);
        }

        List<Object> resultList = createQuery.getResultList();

        boolean hasNext = pageable.isPaged() && resultList.size() > pageSize;

        return new SliceImpl<>(hasNext ? resultList.subList(0, pageSize) : resultList, pageable, hasNext);

    }
}
```

If you observe the above code snippet, to findout whether next set of results present or not (for `hasNext()`) the `SlicedExecution#doExecute` method always fetch extra one element(`createQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize + 1)`) and skip it based on the pageSize condition(`hasNext ? resultList.subList(0, pageSize) : resultList`).

- Application:

  - Page

    > Use when UI/GUI expects to displays all the results at the initial stage of the search/query itself, with page numbers to traverse(ex., bankStatement with pagenumbers)
  - Slice

    > Use when UI/GUI expects to doesnot interested to show all the results at the initial stage of the search/query itself, but intent to show the records to traverse based on scrolling or next button click event (ex., facebook feed search)