# How to Cache Spring JPA Pagination Count Data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm Creating a Simple Spring Boot application with JPA. I have millions of records to retrieve it from a database. in my repository when I call `findAll(Pageable pageable)` it gets the records I want.

But takes lot of time to return me the subset of records. I found it happening because of `count` query.

Is there a way we can cache the `page` response after first call ?

Comment: It's hard to believe that `count` query takes more time than `select` query. Probably issue is somewhere else

Comment: Count queries can affect performance. An alternative would possibly be to return a Slice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918979/page-vs-slice-when-to-use-which

Comment: but I also want count details for the first time, so ui will paginate it

Comment: **No one** will want to page through millions of records.

Comment: right, but i need to provide pagination support, and get the total count once, and don't want to calculate for next page

Comment: Issue your query manually, cache the result and then use a Slice.