# Implement Search specification for pagination

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I implemented this Page request:

```
@GetMapping
public PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> list(@RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                     @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "10") int size) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> result = productRestService.page(pageRequest);
    return result;
}

public PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> page(PageRequest pageRequest){

        Page<Product> pageResult = productService.findAll(pageRequest);
        List<ProductFullDTO> result = pageResult
                .stream()
                .map(productMapper::toFullDTO)
                .collect(toList());

        return new PageImpl<ProductFullDTO>(result, pageRequest, pageResult.getTotalElements());
    }

    public Page<Product> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        return this.dao.findAll(pageRequest);
    }

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    Page<Product> findAllByTypeIn(Pageable page, String... types);

    Page<Product> findAll(Pageable page);
}
```

The question is how to implement search functionality for this `Page` request?
I would like to send params like `type` and `dateAdded` into GET params and return filtered result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Examples. Simple but can only be used for simple searches

```
    @GetMapping("products")
    public Page<ProductFullDTO> findProducts(Product example,
Pageable pageable) {
   return productService.findProductsByExample(example, pageable);
}
```

To be able to search by example, you need make sure your ProductRepository  interface extends from QueryByExampleExecutor:

```
public interface ProductRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Product> {}
```

In your service method, you can simply pass the example object:

```
public Page<ProductFullDTO> findProductsByExample(Product exampleProduct, Pageable pageable) {
    return productRepository.findByExample(Example.of(exampleProduct), pageable).map(ProductFullDTO::new);
}
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.matchers for more information

2. Using JPA Specification. This is useful in case the search parameters are more complex (e.g. when you need to join other entities)

```
    @GetMapping("products")
    public Page<ProductFullDTO> findProducts(@Valid ProductSearchParams params,
Pageable pageable) {
   return productService.findProducts(params, pageable);
}
```

The `ProductSearchParams` class could look like this:

```
public class ProductSearchParams {
   private String type;
   private Date dateAdded;
}
```

To use the search params, we need a Specification. To use this, you need make sure your ProductRepository interface extends from JpaSpecificationExecutor:

```
public interface ProductRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<Product, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {}
```

Since the Specification interface has only one method, we can use a lambda in our service:

```
public Page<ProductFullDTO> findProducts(ProductSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<Product> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getType() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), params.getType()));
        }
        if (params.getDateAdded() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("dateAdded"), params.getDateAdded()));
        }
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return productRepository.findAll(spec, pageable).map(ProductFullDTO::new);
}
```

Using Specification is more powerful, but also a bit more work. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications for information on using Specifications. Using Specifications also allows you to write really elegant expressions, e.g. `customerRepository.findAll( isLongTermCustomer().or(hasSalesOfMoreThan(amount)));`

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the desired behavior in several ways.

Let's forget about the paging parameters for a moment.

First, define a POJO that agglutinates the different fields required as search criteria. For example:

```java
public class ProductFilter {
  private String type;
  private LocalDate dateAdded;

  // Setters and getters omitted for brevity
}
```

This information should be the entry point to your `Controller` search method.

Please, although a `@GetMapping` is perfectly suitable, consider use a `@PostMapping` instead, mainly in order to avoid possible [URL length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) problems <sup>1</sup>:

```java
@PostMapping
public PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> list(ProductFilter filter) {
    //...
}
```

Or to consume your search criteria as JSON payload and `@RequestBody` in your controller:

```java
@PostMapping
public PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> list(@RequestBody ProductFilter filter) {
    //...
}
```

Now, how to deal with pagination related information at `Controller` level? You have several options as well.

- You can include the necessary fields, `page` and `size`, as new fields in `ProductFilter`.

```java
public class ProductFilter {
  private String type;
  private LocalDate dateAdded;
  private int page;
  private int size;

  // Setters and getters omitted for brevity
}
```

- You can create a common POJO to deal with the pagination fields and extend it in your filters (maybe you can work directly with `PageRequest` itself although I consider a simpler approach to create your own POJO for this functionality in order to maintain independence from Spring - an any other framework - as much as possible):

```java
public class PagingForm {
  private int page;
  private int size;
  //...
}

public class ProductFilter extend PagingForm {
  private String type;
  private LocalDate dateAdded;

  // Setters and getters omitted for brevity
}
```

- You can (this is my preferred one) maintain your filter as is, and modify the url to include the paging information. This is especially interesting if you are using `@RequestBody`.

Let's consider this approach to continue with the service layer necessary changes. Please, see the relevant code, pay attention to the inline comments:

```java
@PostMapping
public PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> list(
  @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
  @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "10") int size,
  @RequestBody ProductFilter filter
) {
    PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    // Include your filter information
    PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> result = productRestService.page(filter, pageRequest);
    return result;
}
```

Your `page` method can look like this <sup>2</sup>:

```java
public PageImpl<ProductFullDTO> page(final ProductFilter filter, final PageRequest pageRequest){
  // As far as your repository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor, my advice
  // will be to create a new Specification with the appropriate filter criteria
  // In addition to precisely provide the applicable predicates, 
  // it will allow you to control a lot of more things, like fetch join
  // entities if required, ...
  Specification<Product> specification = buildProductFilterSpecification(filter);
          
  // Use now the constructed specification to filter the actual results
  Page<Product> pageResult = productService.findAll(specification, pageRequest);
  List<ProductFullDTO> result = pageResult
                .stream()
                .map(productMapper::toFullDTO)
                .collect(toList());

  return new PageImpl<ProductFullDTO>(result, pageRequest, pageResult.getTotalElements());
}
```

You can implement the suggested [`Specification`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) over `Product` as you need. Some general tips:

- Always define the `Specification` in a separate class in a method defined for the task, it will allow you to reuse in several places of your code and favors testability.
- If you prefer, in order to improve the legibility of the code, you can use a lambda when defining it.
- To identify the different fields used in your predicate construction, prefer always the use of metamodel classes instead of `String`s for the field name. You can use the [Hibernate Metamodel generator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/topical/html/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html) to generate the necessary artifacts.
- In your specific use case, do not forget to include the necessary `sort` definition to provide consistent results.

In summary, the `buildProductFilterSpecification` can look like this:

```java
public static Specification<Product> buildProductFilterSpecification(final ProjectFilter filter) {
  return (root, query, cb) -> {

    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    final String type = filter.getType();
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(type)) {
      // Consider the use of like on in instead
      predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Product_.type), cb.literal(type)));
    }

    // Instead of dateAdded, please, consider a date range, it is more useful
    // Let's suppose that it is the case
    final LocalDate dateAddedFrom = filter.getDateAddedFrom();
    if (dateAddedFrom != null){
      // Always, specially with dates, use cb.literal to avoid underlying problems    
      predicates.add(
        cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Product_.dateAdded), cb.literal(dateAddedFrom))
      );
    }

    final LocalDate dateAddedTo = filter.getDateAddedTo();
    if (dateAddedTo != null){
      predicates.add(
        cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Product_.dateAdded), cb.literal(dateAddedTo))
      );
    }

    // Indicate your sort criteria
    query.orderBy(cb.desc(root.get(Product_.dateAdded)));

    final Predicate predicate = cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));

    return predicate;
  };
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> As @blagerweij pointed out in his comment, the use of `POST` instead of `GET` will prevent in a certain way the use of caching at HTTP (web server, Spring MVC) level.

Nevertheless, it is necessary to indicate two important things here:

- one, you can safely use a `GET` or `POST` HTTP verb to handle your search, the solution provided will be valid with both verbs with minimal modifications.
- two, the use of one or other HTTP method will be highly dependent in your actual use case:

  - If, for example, you are dealing with a lot of parameters, the URL limit can be a problem if you use `GET` verb. I faced the problem myself several times.
  - If that is not the case and your application is mostly analytical, or at least you are working with static information or data that does not change often, use `GET`, HTTP level cache can provide you great benefits.
  - If your information is mostly operational, with numerous changes, you can always rely on server side cache, at database or service layer level, with Redis, Caffeine, etcetera, to provide caching functionally. This approach will usually provide you a more granular control about cache eviction and, in general, cache management.

---

<sup>2</sup> @blagerweij suggested in his comment the use of `Slice` as well. If you do not need to know the total number of elements of your record set - think, for example, in the typical use case in which you scroll a page and it fires the fetch of a new record set, in a fixed amount, that will be shown in the page -  the use of `Slice` instead of `Page` can provide you great performance benefits. Please, consider review this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918979/page-vs-slice-when-to-use-which), for instance.

In a typical use case, in order to use `Slice` with `findAll` your repository cannot extend `JpaRepository` because in turn it extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` and that interface already provides the method you are using now, `findAll(Pageable pageable)`.

Probably you can expend `CrudRepository` instead and the define a method similar to:

```java
Slice<Product> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

But, I am not sure if you can use `Slice`s with `Specification`s: please, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1311): I am afraid that it is still a WIP.

Comment: To support caching, I would still recommend using GET for reading. Also, no need to use multipart/form-data (unless you're uploading binary files). I would recommend to use Slice instead of Page (since Page requires an additional count query to the DB). Spring data JPA has a lot support builtin already.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment @blagerweij, I really appreciate the feedback. Regarding `multipart/form-data`, of course, I wanted to say _standard_ `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, please, excuse my mind. Any way, I removed that part from the answer. Thank you very much for pointing out the such interesting topics. Please, see my updated answer. Please, feel free to include any further information if you consider it appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make an implementation of the `Specification` interface that you can pass to your JPA repository. The implementation of the `toPredicate` method is where you can build your selection logic.

There is an overload to in the `JpaSpecificationExecutor`:

```
Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

There's a good example of using the `Specification/Repository` interfaces [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications).