# Make count query pagination not + 1 sql statement

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa

I have 1 get list pagination in Spring Data JPA.
When i pass param Pageable to method and get Page 
and see have 2 sql statement run
1. `Select .... from Model` 
2. `Select count(m) from Model`. (get total element of table)
I think have some way to reduce select count and make it in fisrt statement?
Someone can explain my mind?
Thank so much!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644749/way-to-disable-count-query-from-pagerequest-for-getting-total-pages